# How to fix "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get' " with JSON file python

Tags: python, json, attributeerror

I need to compare the value of the `id` key from a dictionary within a DataFrame Column with an integer. But whenever I try to create a boolean mask where I compare the string to the needed string using the `.get()` command, I get an `AttributeError`.

This is the code that I have tried:

```py
index = [d.get('id') for d in json['user']]
mask = [d == 56377143 for d in index]
json[mask]
```

`json` is a DataFrame and `json['user']` of a single row looks like this:

```
 0 {'id': 20626359, 'id_str': '20626359', 'name':...}
```

the error I get is

```
AttributeError                      
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-0ab55ae7f743> in <module>()
      1 #type(json['user'][4].get('id'))
      2 
----> 3 index = [d.get('id') for d in json['user']]
      4 yeeson = [d == 56377143 for d in index]
      5 json[yeeson]

<ipython-input-26-0ab55ae7f743> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 #type(json['user'][4].get('id'))
      2 
----> 3 index = [d.get('id') for d in json['user']]
      4 yeeson = [d == 56377143 for d in index]
      5 json[yeeson]
```

I need to get a boolean mask that gives True if the id from the dictionary is the same as the wanted id.

Comment: do a `type(d)`, it appears not to be a dictionary as you think it is

Comment: You appear to be showing us that `json['user']` is a single dict. Is that correct?

Comment: @Nullman When I check type(d), it returns <class  'dict'> so I don't thinks that's the problem

Comment: Where did you type that? According to the error, `d` became a float

Comment: I wrote a little loop like 'for d in json['user']: print(type(d)) and it returned dict...

Comment: check that ALL the `d` are dicts, i think you have a rogue float in there. you can do this easily with `set([type(d) for d in json['user']])`

Comment: Also, if you're actually using dataframes, then you shouldn't be using list comprehension

Comment: @Nullman You are correct, it returns '{dict, float}'. Is this possibly because of NaN values? Do you have a suggestion on how to change this?

Comment: Well, you could always do `d.get('id') for d in json['user'] if type(d) == dict `

Comment: if you are using pandas you can drop rows with nan in them with [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: I created a loop that checks `type(d)` and adds a 0 if `type(d) == float` and now it works! thank you for your help!